# making images on a website/page unsaveable?

Tags: html, image

I have been trying to find a way to show an image on a webpage but make sure the user wont be able to save it, anyone knows anything about?

Comment: Aside from ways of making it harder for people to download your images, it might be good to consider adding copyright notice on the site and possibly watermarks or signatures. This should "scare off" a lot of people with intentions of using your images. ( http://creativecommons.org/ )

Answer (score 4):

You can make it difficult, but **you cannot make it impossible.**

If an image shows up on screen, it can be screenshotted.

Answer (score 4):

Matt Ball is right. But what you may do is to define a `div`-container and set your image as the `background-image`. In most cases this will do.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with the attributes I added! You can change what to src to.

```
<img src="https://grav-kodeklubb.github.io/cdn/img/icon.png" oncontextmenu="return false;" draggable="false">
```

The `oncontextmenu="return false;"` attribute will prevent right-clicking on the image

The `draggable="false"` will prevent users from dragging the image.

The above solution will go a long way to preventing others from using images from your webpage.

But there's no 100% solution to your request because users can still screenshot the image, and they can also be maybe better protected on the middle of tie image a copyirhgt.

Answer (score 0):

Per **Matt Ball** you won't have much luck keeping it from being saved.

Adding a *watermark* is another option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Edit "customprotectclass" with your own name including the ones containing "customprotectclass".

```css
.customprotectclass { position: relative; display: inline-block; }

.customprotectclass img { vertical-align: bottom; }

.customprotectclass:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="customprotectclass">
  <img src="http://google.com/favicon.ico"/>
</div>
```