# Right click to download pictures, to protect your privacy outlook prevent automatic downloads of this picture

Tags: html, email, outlook

How to send image in html so outlook would not prevent showing that? I have a python script which I use with sending email, The email contains header and footer image but outlook prevent showing that image and blocks it with below error:

> Right click to download pictures, to protect your privacy outlook
>   prevent automatic downloads of this picture.

the Html code is like below:

```
<img width=709 height=131 id="_x0000_i1025" src='./static/img/h.jpg' />
```

what code helps me, so outlook would not prevent images?

Comment: This can be easier from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028508/18754217

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your images use relative urls (uris), so they will never work in an email.

Secondly, you need to add the images as MIME parts to the message and refer to them using a cid, e.g. `<img src="cid:MyCid">,` where `MyCid` is the value of the Content-Id MIME header on the image MIME part.