# Mailchimp email not automatically downloading images in Outlook

Tags: image, email, outlook, mailchimp

I have a mailchimp email that contains quite a few images however do not load automatically in the outlook inbox.

I was wondering if there was a way of automatically loading the images to the email recipients that use outlook.

So far I have investigated that recipients could change their settings by altering the trust center settings as shown [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1182/outlook_download_pictures_automatically_without_right_click/). But as the only comment on that article states that there are problems with Mailchimp.

I have also come across a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994937/right-click-to-download-pictures-to-protect-your-privacy-outlook-prevent-automa). However, not sure where to find my images Cid or not even sure whether this is a viable option.

Below is an image of the problem.

[image]

**Edit (27/10/17):**

The mailchimp images look like this:
https://gallery.mailchimp.com/608ee8ffcd21cef122eb0e6d9/images/765fb2c2-7075-4964-b831-ba5a6d0bc7cd.png

The img is written like this:

```
<img align="center" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/608ee8ffcd21cef122eb0e6d9/images/765fb2c2-7075-4964-b831-ba5a6d0bc7cd.png" width="564" style="max-width: 1000px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="mcnImage">
```

Comment: Realistically you cannot force someone to download images if they don't want to. That is why we usually don't use too many images in email design.

Comment: Can you show your code? are you using absolute image paths?

Comment: Looking at the code it's using the mail chimp gallery, so something similar to this:
https://gallery.mailchimp.com/608ee8ffcd21cef1eb310e6d9/images/345b81e3-e04c-432e-8a7c-64b587cdcd7c.jpg

Comment: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it"

Comment: I changed it a bit to protect sensitive data however the format of the image url is the same. and it would usually just show an image on a blank page

Comment: It does not show up Sorry :)

Comment: ok, please check my edit to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're having the same issue. I was under the impression that this can be resolved by authentication.

https://kb.mailchimp.com/accounts/email-authentication/about-email-authentication

I'm hoping we can convince the guys who manage to DNS server to add this.

Answer (score 3):

We've added domain authentication *and* verification and it hasn't resolved the issue; anyone using Outlook has to 'Mark as Safe' EVERY SINGLE TIME.

Interestingly we receive emails from a rival using Oracle/Bronto email software and this doesn't occur.

Problem is MailChimp is great apart from this one annoying issue.

Comment: Do Oracle/Bronto reference the image as a link or are the inlined as a mime attachment?